# Heartbeat module

Tags: 7, ajax, heartbeat

How do you enable AJAX in [Heartbeat](http://drupal.org/project/heartbeat), such that when you click load older messages, it loads the messages? Currently, when I click the link there is no response whatsoever. Do I need to download any file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to download any file. There was [a recent issue](http://drupal.org/node/1363260) with the refresh functionality that might be applicable to what you are experiencing: In heartbeat.entity.inc, at line 242, the "/js" is missing in front of heartbeat.js so the stream are not refreshing.

Instead of `drupal_get_path('module', 'heartbeat') . '/heartbeat.js'`, that line should be `drupal_get_path('module', 'heartbeat') . '/js/heartbeat.js'`-